# No matching distribution found for spc

Tags: python, installation, pycharm, spc

I use python 3.8.32 bit and I try to install spc 0.3 on my computer but there is an error that appears and stops the installing process. Note that I use Windows 10 10.0, PyCharm 2021.2.1 (Community Edition), and Memory: 980M

The error is explained below :

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import 
 io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = 
 '"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
 y1l465fe\\spc_c62f53289a8d41bcbaf4216f5dfb469c\\setup.py'"'"'; 
 __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install- 
 y1l465fe\\spc_c62f53289a8d41bcbaf4216f5dfb469c\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenized, 
 '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from 
 setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
 '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 
 'C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-euhi7_c6'
      cwd: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
 y1l465fe\spc_c62f53289a8d41bcbaf4216f5dfb469c\
   Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install- 
 y1l465fe\spc_c62f53289a8d41bcbaf4216f5dfb469c\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
     from ez_setup import use_setuptools
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ez_setup'
  ----------------------------------------
 WARNING: Discarding 
  Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info 
 Check the logs for full command output.
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spc (from versions: 0.3)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for spc
```

Can any one help me PLZ?

Comment: According to [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/spc/), `spc` was last released in 2009, and is almost certainly written in Python 2. Your chances of getting it to work are... slim, at best.

Comment: OK, I take that back, someone familiar with `matplotlib` could probably get it in shape, but it'll take some work.

Comment: I want to use erfc function like this line of code:    p_val = spc.erfc(math.fabs(sobs) / math.sqrt(2)   is there any alternate solution?